Vector calculus identities on finite weighted graphs
I am studying the chemotaxis equations on the graph, so I need to generalize the term $\nabla \cdot(v \nabla u)$ from a continuous space to the weighted graph. Here, when I try to use the definition of $\nabla$ i.e. $\mathrm{grad}$ and $\mathrm{div}$ on weight graphs, I find it does not consist with the vector analysis identity that we use commonly in the normal version of vector analysis.
Here I use the definition and notation from Wikipedia. A finite weight graph $G = (V, E, w)$ is defined as a triple for which

$V = \{x_1 , \dots x_n\}$ are nodes/vertices
$E \subset V\times V$ is a finite set of directed edges(here I don't think the direction will significantly change the result in this case)
$w:E \to [0, \infty)$ is an edge weight, and for nodes $x_i$ and $x_j$, $w(x_i,x_j) = w(x_j,x_i)$, which means it is symmetric. Also, $w(x_i,x_j)>0$ iff $x_i \sim x_j$

And we define the following two function spaces:

$\mathcal{H}(V):=\{f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ be the space of (real) vertex functions
$\mathcal{H}(E):=\{F: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ be the space of real edge functions

Then, one can define the following operators on the graph:

Gradient: $\nabla: \mathcal{H}(V) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}(E)$ as $\left(\nabla f\right)\left(x_i, x_j\right) = \sqrt{w\left(x_i, x_j\right)}\left(f\left(x_j\right)-f\left(x_i\right)\right)$
Divergence: $\mathrm{div}: \mathcal{H}(E) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}(V)$ as
$$
\mathrm{div}F(x_i) = \left(-\nabla^* F\right)\left(x_i\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_j \sim x_i} \sqrt{w\left(x_i, x_j\right)}\left(F\left(x_i, x_j\right)-F\left(x_j, x_i\right)\right)
$$
Laplacian: $(\Delta f)(x_i) = \left(\operatorname{div}\left(\nabla f\right)\right)\left(x_i\right)= \sum_{x_j \sim x_i} w\left(x_i, x_j\right)\left(f\left(x_i\right)-f\left(x_j\right)\right) $

My question: how to represent the term $\nabla \cdot(v \nabla u)$ using the above definitions and why the vector identity not correct.
My Attempt:
\begin{aligned}
 \mathrm{div}(v \nabla u)\left(x_i\right)&=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_j \sim x_i} \sqrt{w\left(x_i, x_j\right)}\left(v\left(x_i\right) \nabla u\left(x_i, x_j\right)-v\left(x_j\right) \nabla u\left(x_j, x_i\right)\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_j \sim x_i} w\left(x_i, x_j\right)\left(v\left(x_i\right)\left(u\left(x_j\right)-u\left(x_i\right)\right)-v\left(x_j\right)\left(u\left(x_i\right)-u\left(x_j\right)\right)\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_j \sim x_j} w\left(x_i, x_j\right)\left(u\left(x_j\right)-u\left(x_i\right)\right)\left(v\left(x_j\right)+v\left(x_i\right)\right) .
\end{aligned}
But according to the normal version vector analysis, we expect the following identity:
$$
    \mathrm{div}(v \nabla u) = \nabla v \cdot \nabla u + v \Delta u
$$
The first term is an inner product and it is defined as following:
$$
    \langle\nabla v, \nabla u \rangle(x_i) =\sum_{x_j \sim x_i} 
w(x_i,x_j) \left(u\left(x_j\right)-u\left(x_i\right)\right)\left(v\left(x_j\right)-v\left(x_i\right)\right)
$$
and for the second term we have
\begin{aligned}
(v \Delta u)\left(x_i\right) & =v\left(x_i\right) \Delta u\left(x_i\right) \\
& =v\left(x_i\right) \sum_{x_j \sim x_i} w\left(x_i, x_j\right)\left(u\left(x_i\right)-u\left(x_j\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
Adding these two we can see that $LHS \neq RHS$
Remark: In some other notes, there are some other definitions, but most of them just change the position of the weight function and some positive and negative signs. I don't think this will solve the problem.

Shouldn't the inner product formula involve the graph weights?

@TravisWillse Thanks for point that out. But it still seems not so correct. More over, if we consider further the node weight (associate a positive node function to each node), the situation seems much worse
